# MS XML - xml native function throws Namespace Manager or XSLT context required error

Tags: c#, xpath, msxml

I have this query ***translate(string(current-date(),'Z-',''))*** , but throws Namespace or XSLT context required exception when tried with following code fragment.
 private string parseXpath(string parseString, params object[] args) {

```
    string[] xs = parseString.Split(new string[] { "xpath::", "{", "}" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    XPathNavigator nav = ((XmlDocument)args[0]).CreateNavigator();
        try {
        var xn = nav.Evaluate(xs[0]);
        switch (xn.GetType().Name) {
            case "String": return (string)xn;
            case "XPathSelectionIterator": return nav.SelectSingleNode(xs[0]).Value;
            case "Double": return xn.ToString();
            case "Boolean": return xn.ToString().ToLower();

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        this.log(new XPathException(ex.Message));
        this.log(new XPathException(string.Format("No data for xpath ->{0}", parseString)));
        if (parseString.Contains("N104") || parseString.Contains("N401") || parseString.Contains("N402")) return "  ";
        if (parseString.Contains("N403")) return "   ";
        return " ";
    }
    return parseString;
}
```

I have tested the same expression on https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output and it does yield expected result.

Is this a limitation on MS-XML ? or is there a work-around to get it working ?

Comment: can you please include in your example the .xml and .xslt, i.e. what is args[0] and xs[0].

Comment: I have included the where xs[0] in the code fragment. This has no xslt transform. the xs[0]=translate(string(current-date(),'Z-','')) , as you see this string does not point to any axis in the xml but attempting to use xpath/xslt functions (i.e. translate, string and current-date).

Comment: p.s: I used <root></root> as input to the freeformatter.

Comment: I get 'Unable to perform XPath operation. System function string() cannot be called with 3 arguments' on freeformatter, and 'Function 'string' in 'translate(string(current-date(),'Z-',''))' has an invalid number of arguments.' with your .NET code above. Are you sure you've got the 'string' function right?

Comment: I think you may not be creating the XmlDocument passed to args correctly. Can you post the code used to pass it. I am using 'var x = new XmlDocument();
            x.LoadXml("<root></root>");
            parseXpath("translate(string(current-date(),'Z-',''))", x);